# Which is best, Java or Xml for developing android apps

Tags: android, xml

I have know core java, I want to develop android apps, in few sites I saw apps in XML in few Java.Which is best and easy to use Java or XML?

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you are talking about the UI, not the complete app:

For everything statically I use XML, because it is easy to find in the structure of your project.

Some parts you want to create dynamically and you have no other choice then to use Code. Be smart, in this, so if you have to add several Views that look the same do this

1. Make an XML with your views
2. In the loop where you are adding the several Views, inflate this xml, set your id's etc, and add them

You can have all the basics, styles etc in your XML, and still add stuff dynamically.

Maybe you want to check out some of the [hello world code](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)?

Answer (score 5):

You can't build apps in XML.  You use XML to define the UI and a few other things, but the logic of the app itself has to be written in Java.

Comment: ok To develop java we need to open .java file then for XML which file ---main.xml?

Comment: You're not going to learn to build android apps by asking people on here which file to open... if you want to learn to build android apps, go do the tutorials: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Answer (score 1):

Android development is in Java, but when you declare the layouts (where the buttons and so are going to be on the screen) you do that in XML.

So you have to use BOTH anyways.

XML for layout
JAVA for programming your app