# Difference between loading menu resources (xml vs java)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a android game project that need some *.png files for menu. I wonder which method is better for loading resources?

I have 2 ways:

- By my class "TextureManager" (very similar to Image class)
- By android method: define resources in xml and reference through R.java

Any pluses and minuses of this two solution?

Comment: thx for answer. You think its only difference? (load order)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4595912/1012284